# Save file from anchor tag using Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

Is it possible to have regular anchor tags pointing to files that open a dialog for saving the file? Like a web browser would.

For example:

```
<a download href="documents/somefile.pdf">Download</a>
```

And having that anchor-tag triggering a Save file-dialog on click?

I've tried using `file://absolute-path-to-the-dir/documents/somefile.pdf` and it wants to open the file in the application rather than download it.

Update:
In a later version of Electron than I used when I wrote this question the behaviour is as I want it to be, a window opens that asks the user to save the file.

However, in the case of external links and wanting to keep the Electron window only for internal links and open the external ones in the default OS choice, the answer by Joshua Smith can do exactly that.

Comment: Any luck finding a solution for this? I'm looking to do the exact same thing.

Comment: @MobileSam None so far. I've given up trying for now. Will try to find an answer again once I have more time.

Comment: After some research, I found an answer here:

https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-access-atom-shell-apis-within-angularjs-for-opening-a-file-save-dialog/14376/4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I'm doing is two-fold.

```
mainWindow.webContents.on('new-window', function(event, url) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Handing off to O/S: "+url);
    shell.openExternal(url);
});
```

That is there so that whenever a page in my app wants to open a new window, that'll happen in an actual browser. This is also good for opening PDFs and such.

Then I just make sure that any download links use target=_blank or window.open() and the download will happen in the user's browser.

Comment: For those new to electron: shell is require("electron").shell;

Answer (score 7):

In script you can use the save file dialog by using the dialog module:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var dialog = require('dialog');
dialog.showSaveDialog(options, function (filePath) {
    fs.writeFile(filePath, pdfContents, function (err) {
        if(err) console.error(err);
    });
});
```

Here is the documentation:

https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md#dialogshowsavedialogbrowserwindow-options-callback